# The catch-block doesn't catch throw method of a stub

Tags: sinon, sinon-chai

Let say I have a method in class `UserService` as below

```
//userService.ts

async createUser(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) {
    try {
      const input = plainToClass(SignupInput, event.body);
      const error = await AppValidationError(input);
      if (error) return errorReponse(404, error);

      const salt = await getSalt();
      const hashedPassword = await getHasedPassword(input.password, salt);

      const data = await this.repository.createAccount({
        email: input.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        phone: input.phone,
        userType: "BUYER",
        salt,
      });

      if(!data){
        return errorReponse(400, "invalid format")
      }
      return successReponse(data);
    } catch (error) {

      return errorReponse(500, error);
    }
```

**I would like to verify if the `this.repository.createAccount` funtion throws error or be rejected, the `catch-block` statment is reached. Here is my spec**

```
//userService.spec.ts

describe("user service", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = createSandbox();
    userRepo = sandbox.createStubInstance(UserRepository);
    userService = new UserService(userRepo);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
 
    it.only("when there is error thrown, Then the errorResponse() should be called", async () => {
      const expectedError = new Error("oops");
      const spiedErrorResp = sandbox.spy(respUtilts, "errorReponse");

      sandbox.stub(passwordUtils, "getSalt").resolves("#salt"); //(depend-1)
      sandbox.stub(passwordUtils, "getHasedPassword").resolves("#hash"); //(depend-2)
      sandbox
        .stub(UserRepository.prototype, "createAccount")
        .throws(expectedError); // (1)

      await userService.createUser(event1);

      sandbox.assert.calledOnce(spiedErrorResp);
      sandbox.assert.calledWith(spiedErrorResp, 500, expectedError);
    });
  });
});
```

Although  the `createAccount`(at the line(1) in spec file) is configured to be thrown  (or rejected), the running flow does not reach to `catch-block` statement (as I debug, the `const data` in `userService.ts` file is `undefined`, so, the flow still be in the `try-block`. I have not sure this is the true behavior of sinon; or may I configure wrong something. Would you share your some ideas

Notes that: If I configure for one of two lines in spec file (depend-1, depend-2), the `catch-block` in `userService.ts` is reached as my expectation